# python pandas obtain number of active subscribers from subscription start date and duration

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-range

I have a pandas dataframe `df` for which each row contains a `start_date` (which is the index too) and a `duration` (in days) for subscriptions.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date':['2018-01-01','2018-01-05']})
df['start_date'] = df['start_date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta([10,8], unit='D')
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + df['duration']
```

I'd like to plot the number of subscribers over time.

My idea was to create another data frame `subscribers`:

```
active_subscribers = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(),end=df['end_date'].max()),
    'Number': 0,
})
active_subscribers.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

`Date`covers the entire period of time when at least one subscriber is active. Then I was thinking creating date ranges for each subscription and adding them to the `Number` column like so:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for this_date in pd.date_range(start=index, end=row['end_date']):
        active_subscribers[this_date]['Number'] += 1
```

but this returns the following error:

`KeyError: Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00', freq='D')`

What I was hoping to get is a `Number`column that looks like this:

```
Date         Number
2018-01-01     1
2018-01-02     1
2018-01-03     1
2018-01-04     1
2018-01-05     2
2018-01-06     2
2018-01-07     2
2018-01-08     2
2018-01-09     2
2018-01-10     2
2018-01-11     1
2018-01-12     1
2018-01-13     1
```

Where the column `Number`contains the number of active subscribers that day.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just edited the question. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I believe you're getting the `KeyError` because you're trying to access a column whose name is (the value of) `this_date`. However, i think it would be better to tally (perhaps using a `Counter`) and then convert to a dataframe. The incrementing a cell in a dataframe feels goofy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) for new `DataFrame` and then get new column by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01','2018-01-05']))
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta([10,8], unit='D')
df['end_date'] = df.index + df['duration']
print (df)
           duration   end_date
2018-01-01  10 days 2018-01-11
2018-01-05   8 days 2018-01-13

df = df.rename_axis('start_date').reset_index()
com = [pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.start_date, r.end_date)) for r in df.itertuples()]
df1 = pd.concat(com).reset_index()
df1.columns=['Date','Number']
df1 = df1.groupby('Date')['Number'].size().reset_index()
print (df1)
         Date  Number
0  2018-01-01       1
1  2018-01-02       1
2  2018-01-03       1
3  2018-01-04       1
4  2018-01-05       2
5  2018-01-06       2
6  2018-01-07       2
7  2018-01-08       2
8  2018-01-09       2
9  2018-01-10       2
10 2018-01-11       2
11 2018-01-12       1
12 2018-01-13       1
```

It is faster as `iterrows` solution:

```
In [288]: %timeit (iterrows_sol(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 51.1 ms per loop

In [289]: %timeit (itertupl_sol(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01','2018-01-05'] * 10))
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta([10,8,2,3,7,2,1,9,1,20,7,18,9,0,3,20,10,8,3,15] , unit='D')
df['end_date'] = df.index + df['duration']
print (df)
           duration   end_date
2018-01-01  10 days 2018-01-11
2018-01-05   8 days 2018-01-13
2018-01-01   2 days 2018-01-03
2018-01-05   3 days 2018-01-08
2018-01-01   7 days 2018-01-08
2018-01-05   2 days 2018-01-07
2018-01-01   1 days 2018-01-02
2018-01-05   9 days 2018-01-14
2018-01-01   1 days 2018-01-02
2018-01-05  20 days 2018-01-25
2018-01-01   7 days 2018-01-08
2018-01-05  18 days 2018-01-23
2018-01-01   9 days 2018-01-10
2018-01-05   0 days 2018-01-05
2018-01-01   3 days 2018-01-04
2018-01-05  20 days 2018-01-25
2018-01-01  10 days 2018-01-11
2018-01-05   8 days 2018-01-13
2018-01-01   3 days 2018-01-04
2018-01-05  15 days 2018-01-20
```

Functions:

```
def iterrows_sol(df):
    active_subscribers = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df['end_date'].max()),
    'Number': 0,})

    active_subscribers.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for this_date in pd.date_range(start=index, end=row['end_date']):
            active_subscribers.loc[this_date, 'Number'] += 1
    return active_subscribers

def itertupl_sol(df):
    df = df.rename_axis('start_date').reset_index()
    com = [pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.start_date,r.end_date)) for r in df.itertuples()]
    df1 = pd.concat(com).reset_index()
    df1.columns=['Date','Number']
    df1 = df1.groupby('Date')['Number'].size().reset_index()
    return (df1)
```